# Is ubuntu sso provider intended for normal people?

Tags: single-sign-on

I am looking for an SSO / OpenID provider software to run on my server. Can ubuntu sso provider be recommended for that? Is it intended for normal people in terms of maintainability, stability, security, etc.?

If so, can it be used with Mysql or even better LDAP? Or is it porstgres only?
Are there any packages available or are there plans to get this software into the ubuntu repositories?